# Get Attention Of Chatbot

Tags: c#, if-statement, chat

I have tried to do some searching on the best way to do this, but I am not quite sure what to search; so I was hoping for some help here if anyone would mind.

In my C# form I have:

- InputTextbox
- OutputTextbox

I am using "InputTextbox_KeyDown" to run a growing number of "if" statements. ie:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter & InputputTextbox.Text.Contains("hello")
OutputTextbox.Text = "hi there"
```

I am calling the chatbot "Penny", and would like it only to look for further commands once the word "penny" is entered into the InputTextbox. (ie: if the user types in "hello", nothing would happen because they haven't gotten "Penny's" attention).

Something like this:

```
if (KeyCode == Keys.Enter & InputTextbox.Text.Contains("penny")
then
*look for the next InputTextbox.Text*
```

Does that make any sense?

Comment: *Does that make any sense?* Not really...

Comment: Sorry. Ah... Basically I want the program to only execute commands once the phrase "penny" has been entered into the InputTextbox and been replied to with "hi there".

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: whats the question?  if you tried something that doesnt work, tell us in what way it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set a flag to indicate 'penny' has been entered

```
private bool _isActive = false;

public void YourMethod()
{
    if (!_isActive)
    {
        if (KeyCode == Keys.Enter && InputTextbox.Text.Contains("penny"))
        {
            _isActive = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && InputputTextbox.Text.Contains("hello"))
        {
            OutputTextbox.Text = "hi there";
        }

        // other if's
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt you just have this at the top of your InputTextbox_KeyDown method?

```
if(KeyCode != Keys.Enter) return;
if(!InputTextbox.Text.Contains("penny")) return;
/*
 * rest of chat responses
 */
```